# how to read XML file from an URL in android?

Tags: android, xml

I have a XML file on the server that has a version tag.

I want to get that version and compare it with my app version and if they weren't same show a snackbar.

But I don't know how to read XML file plz help me.

This is the XML file on server:

http://adpring.com/uploads/faravani.xml

Comment: Try this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request the xml content with `HTTPURLConnection` and then use `XmlPullParser` to parse. Below is a simple example.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        private static final String TAG_VERSION = "version";

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                XmlPullParser pullParser = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
                URL url = new URL("http://adpring.com/uploads/faravani.xml");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();

                if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "run: http request error");
                    return;
                }

                pullParser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

                int eventType = pullParser.getEventType();

                String currentTag = null;
                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {

                    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        currentTag = pullParser.getName();
                    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {

                    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                        if (currentTag != null && TAG_VERSION.equals(currentTag)) {
                            currentTag = null;
                            Log.d(TAG, "run: version string " + pullParser.getText().trim());
                        }
                    }

                    eventType = pullParser.next();
                }
            } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not an XML this is Json .

second of all :

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("YOUR STRING HERE");
```

than you will able to pull from the object the value you need per key , version in your case .

Comment: sorry i forgot to change it to XML. So what should i do for XML?